# Geocoding via Google Maps API is failing randomly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coldfusion, sql-server-2014, coldfusion-10

I have a form containing 3 different types of addresses on it (Physical, Mailing and Business). When I submit the form I use the code below to get the latitude and longitude for the address(es).

However, I'm getting sporadic results. Sometimes they all work and other times only 1 works, etc. I'm looking for ideas as to why it is acting like this.

```
<cfif form.f_address IS NOT "" AND form.f_city IS NOT "" AND form.f_state IS NOT "" AND form.f_zip IS NOT "">

    <CFQUERY datasource="#datasource#" name="get_mstate">
      select state_abb from states
      where state_id = '#form.f_state#'
    </CFQUERY>

    <cfoutput>
        <cfset maddress2geocode = "#Form.f_address#, #form.f_city#, #get_mstate.state_abb# #form.f_zip#">
        <cfset mapi = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#URLEncodedFormat(maddress2geocode)#&sensor=false">

        <cfhttp url="#mapi#"></cfhttp>

        <cfset mresponse = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.FileContent)>

        <cftry>
            <cfset mpoint = mresponse["results"][1]["geometry"]["location"]>

            #SerializeJSON(mpoint)#

            <cfquery name="insert_mgeocode" datasource="#datasource#">
                UPDATE contactrecord
                SET lat = <cfqueryparam value="#mpoint.lat#">,
                    long = <cfqueryparam value="#mpoint.lng#">
                WHERE contactrecord_id = '#newid#'
            </cfquery>

        <cfcatch>

            <cfquery name="insert_mfailed" datasource="#datasource#">
                UPDATE contactrecord
                SET failed_geocode = '1'
                WHERE contactrecord_id = '#newid#'
            </cfquery>

        </cfcatch>
        </cftry>

    </cfoutput>
</cfif>

<cfif form.f_paddress IS NOT "" AND form.f_pcity IS NOT "" AND form.f_pstate IS NOT "" AND form.f_pzip IS NOT "">

    <CFQUERY  datasource="#datasource#" name="get_pstate">
    select state_abb from states
    where state_id = '#form.f_pstate#'
    </CFQUERY>

    <cfoutput>
        <cfset paddress2geocode = "#Form.f_paddress#, #form.f_pcity#, #get_pstate.state_abb# #form.f_pzip#">
        <cfset papi = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#URLEncodedFormat(paddress2geocode)#&sensor=false">

        <cfhttp url="#papi#"></cfhttp>

        <cfset presponse = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.FileContent)>

        <cftry>
            <cfset ppoint = presponse["results"][1]["geometry"]["location"]>

            #SerializeJSON(ppoint)#

            <cfquery name="insert_pgeocode" datasource="#datasource#">
                UPDATE contactrecord
                SET phy_lat = <cfqueryparam value="#ppoint.lat#">,
                    phy_long = <cfqueryparam value="#ppoint.lng#">
                WHERE contactrecord_id = '#newid#'
            </cfquery>

        <cfcatch>

            <cfquery name="insert_pfailed" datasource="#datasource#">
                UPDATE contactrecord
                SET failed_geocode = '1'
                WHERE contactrecord_id = '#newid#'
            </cfquery>

        </cfcatch>
        </cftry>

    </cfoutput>
</cfif>

<cfif form.f_baddress IS NOT "" AND form.f_bcity IS NOT "" AND form.f_bstate IS NOT "" AND form.f_bzip IS NOT "">

    <CFQUERY  datasource="#datasource#" name="get_bstate">
        select state_abb from states
        where state_id = '#form.f_bstate#'
    </CFQUERY>

    <cfoutput>
        <cfset baddress2geocode = "#Form.f_baddress#, #form.f_bcity#, #get_bstate.state_abb# #form.f_bzip#">
        <cfset bapi = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#URLEncodedFormat(baddress2geocode)#&sensor=false">

        <cfhttp url="#bapi#"></cfhttp>

        <cfset bresponse = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.FileContent)>

        <cftry>
            <cfset bpoint = bresponse["results"][1]["geometry"]["location"]>

            #SerializeJSON(bpoint)#

            <cfquery name="insert_bgeocode" datasource="#datasource#">
                UPDATE contactrecord
                SET bus_lat = <cfqueryparam value="#bpoint.lat#">,
                    bus_long = <cfqueryparam value="#bpoint.lng#">
                WHERE contactrecord_id = '#newid#'
            </cfquery>

        <cfcatch>

            <cfquery name="insert_bfailed" datasource="#datasource#">
                UPDATE contactrecord
                SET failed_geocode = '1'
                WHERE contactrecord_id = '#newid#'
            </cfquery>

        </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: What error do you get when it "fails"?

Comment: I'm not seeing an error, it does set the failed_geocode flag to 1....I have added the key param and removed the sensor param....I'm testing now, will let you know

Comment: NOTE: It looks like you've cut out some of the non-relevant code for this display, but please make sure to close up the injection holes. `where state_id = '#form.f_bstate#'` makes it difficult for me to see the rest of the code. :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not including the (now mandatory) `key` parameter in the request.

(as an aside, you are including the `sensor` parameter, which is no longer required)